# How to call props or state inside const using react navigation

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm a newbie in react native and I'm really having a hard time conditioning my initialroute. I'm trying to use props inside the navigator but I got an error => this.props.users.id is undefined

```
    const MyHome = DrawerNavigator({
            Login: {screen: Login},
            Home: {screen: Home},
            History: {screen: History},
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: rhis.props.users.id === null ? "Login" : "Home",
            contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><SideBar {...props}/
</ScrollView>,
        },
    );
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: In your code snippet, you use `rhis.props.users.id`. Can you confirm that this typo is not present in the original code?

Comment: In this part I'm using redux where => this.props.users.id is saved in my local


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.dataReducer.users,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyHome);